# Best way to share Java variables between classes

Tags: java, variables, member

I have an odd problem in Java.  I can solve it but the solution seems inefficient.

I have a class, which simplified is

```
 class Zot
 { 
      double edges[];
  }
```

The problem is that in many cases I want instance A and instance B to share ONE of the edge instances.  In other words, instance A may allocate edge[2] and want instance B to share edge[2].  This is easy enough in that I can just set instance B to point at instance's A edge[2].  But how can I do it efficiently?  If I allocate the edges[] in instance A, I can then simply assign B's instance to point to A.  But often I only want to allocate a single edge (e.g. edge[2]) in A and then assign it in B.  But in Java, one cannot (as far as I know) allocate a single member of an array (as one can in C++).  Ideally, I only want to allocate the useful member and assign it.  I could, of course, allocate all 4 members, assign the ones I need, then set the  unwanted members to null  and let GC clean it all up, but if there are hundreds or thousands of instances that seems clumsy.

Suggestions?

Comment: When you say "share edge[2]" do you mean share the array of two elements, or share element 2 of said array?

Comment: Almost certainly a larger object will hold the edges of your graph as well as the sides that correspond to these edges.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare and allocate `double edges[]` outside of both classes, then pass this array as a parameter in the constructor into both of the instances that want to share it.

In Java an array is also an object. When you make an instance like `double edges[] = new double[2];` `edges` will be passed around as a pointer, not as a copy.

This means if you make a change in the array in your class A, then class B will also see this change.

Comment: +1 you wrote it better than me :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  However, it seems to be somewhat cumbersome at best. Suppose I am allocating an array of 1000x1000 of object A.  Passing an array to each one will be cumbersome at best.  Again, I can do it the way I suggested but it seems wasteful on GC.  But perhaps I am not seeing the easy solution.

Comment: And they would all share the same array? Or only some of them will? If only some, then you should consider making a provider - a class that will hold the arrays for you, and you would be able to get these arrays inside your classes. To make it work you still either need to make the provider static, or pass it into each object in the constructor (or some other way - for example, with a setter)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have been more exlicit in the beginning. The use case is a NxM matrix of cells which represent a landscape.  So each cell has some member variables as well as four edges, north, east, south, west.  Obviously the edges are shared between adjacent cells.  What I'd like to achieve is to have the edge members be literally shared between adjacent cells.  I wrote this same algorithm originally in C++ a number of years ago.  Now, I'd like to implement it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you appear to want to share an individual element from your `edges` array between classes, and not share the whole array itself.

If your `edges` array was an array of `Object`s then this would be possible, and could make sense.  However, since your array is a primitive array then there is no real concept of sharing an individual element.

You can assign an element of your array to equal the element of another array, but subsequent changes to the element in one array will not be reflected in the other array.

You can share the entire array between classes, in which case any changes will be reflected in both arrays (well, there is only one array, so both classes will see the changes to the single array that they both reference).

**Most importantly:**
When you declare an array of primitives in java, the memory is allocated immediately so there is no benefit (or mechanism) to declare only a single element of the array.  So with your current data model, there is no reason for you to not predeclare your arrays since you cannot save space with them.